# Accessing random lsb bit in steganography

Tags: java, aes, steganography

I'm trying to do audio steganography. Before hiding data inside audio I encrypt the data with aes and then I embed bits at lsb in sequential bytes. The recovery and aes decryption works fine.

But if I try random bits for lsb it gives me the following error:

> -->Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

the error points to

```
public byte[] decr**strong text**yptText(byte[] byteCipherText,Key secKey) throws Exception {
        // AES defaults to AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding in Java 7
        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        byte[] bytePlainText = aesCipher.doFinal(byteCipherText);
```

Comment: Are you sure you extract all of the correct bytes you embed? You show us only 3 lines of code, which is where the error might be raised, but the offending logic could be earlier in your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. See [PKCS padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7), note that PKCS#5 is a misnomer for PKCS#7 WRT AES because the AES implementation developers were to lazy to include the correct option name.
2. Because PKCS#7 padding has format requirements and there few byte sequences (~ 1^16 + 2^16 + ... + 15^16) that form correct padding out of 256^16 possible byte sequences the chance that random bytes would form valid PKCS#7 padding is very small.
3. You might be better off using CTR mode which does not require padding, just a unique key/counter pair for each encryption.